# How to keep basic formatting when store html to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net textbox multiline. I would like to store basic text formatting like next line brake.

example:

```
lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
```

so when I output to literal control it shows the same way

here is my code

when store

```
private string KeepBasicFormating(string text)
        {
            var temp = text;
            temp = Server.HtmlEncode(temp);
            temp = temp.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
            temp = temp.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
            return temp;
        }
```

when outout

```
<asp:Literal ID="LcNotes" Mode="Transform" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
LcNotes.Text = storedText;
```

but it shows as one line text without any formatting

```
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

Comment: You would be **much** better advised to stored the text *without* formatting, and apply formatting (when necessary) when displaying it.

Comment: could you please show me an example?

Comment: Are you sure that the \r\n exist ? and not only \n exist on the text enter ? I think that the issue is the enter here.

Comment: Thank you Aristos. you are right it has to be just \n

Answer (score 0):

Use DIV instead:

```
 <div ID="div" runat="server"></div>
    div.InnerHtml = storedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
... Mode="PassThrough" ...
```